# If /Then formula with result being highlighted in green of red

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, colors

What formula is derived for the following conditions;

E1 =   If B1 is less than or equal to (C1+D1)/2 then result is colored green
E1 =   If B1 is greater than to (C1+D1)/2 then result is colored red

F1 =   If B1 is greater than 1.5*A1 then result is colored green
F1 =   If B1 is less than or equal to 1.5*A1 then result is colored red

For Example : If

```
B1 = 100; 
C1 =70 ; 
D1=105;
```

Add: E1 `=C1  + D1` *(70 + 105 = 175)*

Divide by 2: =87.5

Then E1 `=(C1 + D1)/2` = 87.5

and E1 should be colored red, since `B1 > E1`  (*100 > 87.5)*

Comment: you need the formular

Comment: the way i work with it is have the if return a text eg 'yes' then use conditional formating to change color where the text returned is yes.

Comment: Is E1 the result? and =(C1+D1)/2  and F1=1.5*A1?

Comment: Is E1 the result? Yes E1 is the result ; Example below

Comment: Is E1 the result? Yes E1 is the result ; Example :   If B1 = 100; C1 =70 ; D1=105;  adding C1 (70)+ D1(105) = 175 divide by 2 = 87.5  Then 87.5=E1 and E1 will be colored red

Answer (score 1):

If you need to color E1 for B1<=(C1+D1)/2 green, select the cells in column E if you want more than E1 and

1. click Conditional Formatting,
2. New Rule,
3. Use Formula to determine which cells to Format,
4. in the box under Format values where this formula is true write:
   `=B1<=(C1+D1)/2` 
   And Format Green

if E1=(C1+D1)/2 you can use:
`=E1 >B1` and format Green
Do the same as above (1,2,3,4)with column E and write the new rule:
`=B1>(C1+D1)/2` and format Red

Repeat with F1 and change the Rule to:
`=B1 >1.5*A1` and format Green
`=B1 <= 1.5*A1` and Format Red

If F1 = 1.5*A1 you can write the rule: `=F1<B1` and color Green